# Homescreen sliding effect for Web App

Tags: javascript, iphone, animation, swipe, web-applications

I have a requirement where I need to slide divs in and out of a screen given the users swipe gesture.

I am looking for a javaScript library/decent tutorial that will let me create an effect like the iPhone home screen where you can swipe left and right and have a card/screen slide in/out. It is important it is NOT a framework like Sencha or jqTouch. Essentially I need swipe gesture support and a smooth sliding transition.

Also any effects need to be smooth on the device. (use CSS3 animation (with hardware acceleration) as I need the experience to be smooth.

Targeted devices are Android and iPhone.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Hope you have a licence from Nokia to use a swipe for navigation, they might [sue you like they have Apple](http://moconews.net/article/419-nokias-extends-patent-fight-against-apple-to-europe-with-table/). I think it [cost Apple a lot](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/Nokia-Apple-settle-drawnout-apf-1905744729.html?x=0).

Comment: Did I say swipe? I meant swip. It's like a swipe, just shorter, with a little more angle. I am going to patent it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some jQuery plugins you could use to achieve what you are looking to do without the full overhead of Sencha or jqTouch.  These would still require jQuery and the plugin but I imagine if you are doing any reasonable web app or interface you are using jQuery :]

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/touch

But here are multiple options, one should work to get the slide effect you are looking for or allow you to handle that gesture appropriately.

Comment: This is a great reference. Thanks.